# Преобразовать get запрос (строка) в JSON (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, url, json, express, get

Ребят, помогите. Возможно, я и не правильно делаю изначально.
Вобщем нужно написать восстановление пароля пользователя.
Для этого отправляю на почту письмо с ссылкой вида:

```
site.ru/auth/change/?user=nikname&code=секретный_ключ
```

При переходе по ссылке, проверяю данные в гет запросе, на существование данных параметров в коллекции, если все в порядке на этой же странице выводится форма для отправки нового пароля POST запросом.
И тут столкнулся с проблемой:
Не понимаю, как правильно передать данные GET вместе с POST запросом.
Допехал только до того, чтобы распарсить req.headers.referer, где я получаю ссылку с нужными параметрами (приведенную выше). Теперь нужно как то преобразовать GET данные в JSON для повторной проверки и изменения пароля.

Возможно пишу костыли, может быть есть какие то другие варианты получить уже готовый JSON с данными в GET запросе. Ну или как распарсить URL преобразовав в JSON?

Нужно получить следующее:

```
{
    user: "nikname",
    code: "секретный_ключ"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    url = require("url"),
    qs = require("querystring"),
    ...
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var query = url.parse(request.url).query,
      params = qs.parse(query);

// params - это объект, в котором свойства поименно совпадают с параметрами запроса
// например если есть ?id=10001, то в params будет свойство params.id, равное 10001 и так далее

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Эм,

```
<form method='POST' action='/api.php?user=nikname&code=key'>
<input type='text' name='password'>
</form>
```

Comment: Немного не то надо. Пока сделал два скрытых инпута и запихнул в них get запросы. Но хочется что то по проще, не прибегаю к изменению в форме.